# Android studio unable to find valid certification path to requested target for kotlin jar after update

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

Just Upgraded Android Studio to 4.1 and gradle version to 4.1.0

I get this error on build:

Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
> Could not download kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.0.5.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.0.5)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-metadata-jvm/0.0.5/kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.0.5.jar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-metadata-jvm/0.0.5/kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.0.5.jar?referrer'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have tried invalidate cache/restart, clead and rebuild and connecting from an unrestricted wifi network. I also tried to roll back to version 4.0.2 but the problem still occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: I added mavenCentral() in project level gradle repositories and the build succeeded. Why  is this happening?

Comment: [https://www.programmersought.com/article/88694727260/] try this

Comment: The link is broken now.